# jQuery console error: $(this).effect is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been staring at my code for hours now trying to work out why this seemingly simple play around with jQuery isn't working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>title</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="test">
        <meta name="description" content="test">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <p class='box' id='title'>&quot;test&quot;</p>
        <div class='gallery'>
            <p class='tNail' id='one'>
            <p class='tNail' id='two'>
            <p class='tNail' id='three'>
            <div class='clear'></div>
            <p class='tNail' id='four'>
            <p class='tNail' id='five'>
            <p class='tNail' id='six'>
            <div class='clear'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
        <p class='footer'>test 2011 <a href='#'>test</a></p>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".tNail").click(function()
            {
                $(this).effect("scale", {percent:200, direction:'both'}, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

I've tried using noConflict() to no avail. If anyone can shed some light I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the *actual* error message? The one you've quoted seems impossible...

Comment: You sure you have jQuery.js in your **current** folder?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the jquery file and renamed it to jquery.js
honestly, my error is: ${this}.effect is not a function

Comment: What does noConflict have to do with this...

Comment: I saw a lot of problems with error reports of "... is not a function" and many people solved their problems with noConflict. Thought I'd give it a shot but it didn't work.

Comment: @Lee I've edited your question title to what I think the error message must have been. If this is wrong, please re-edit it.

Comment: Yes that's more appropriate, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ah, looking again, I think the error message is probably "`$(this).effect` is not a function" (which is rather different from `${this}`). You haven't loaded jQuery UI, which is where the [`effect`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/effect) method is defined.

Include the jQuery UI library and try again.

Comment: Ah, I thought the UI functions were part of the jquery core. Thanks.